# Is this Conditional Typing Needed?

Tags: typescript

I saw a typescript code like below:

```
type UnionKeys<T> = T extends T ? keyof T : never;
```

I wonder is the "T extends T" needed, I think the right side of assignment always evaluates to true, thus only the first branch "keyof T" is returned as the final type, the second branch is never returned. This is true even when T is of type *unknown*, *any* and *never* cases. Can someone help with this my doubt ?

Comment: Yes, the previous answer referred by this site's maintainer is relevant, this doubt was answered there. It is related to a typescript feature called "Distributive Conditional Type" I am going to delete this question.